# Image in UIImageView glitches, how to stop this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I use Xcode 5.1.1 single view application.

I have 2 view controllers. I'm using unwind segues to go from view Controller 1 to VC2. I have a BACK button in VC1. When I tap that BACK button in simulator it takes me to VC2 and the bird character glitches for 1 second and then moves normally again. How do i get rid of the glitch? By the way, When i used just modal segues to go to VC2, in VC2 the bird character would glitch and then disappear completely off the screen. With unwind segues bird character glitches for 1 second and then moves normally. In VC2 where the bird is I programmatically placed in image view with...

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tree.png"]];
```

...in VC1 i manually put up an image and programmed that image to scroll.

I made a bare minimum app to show you the coding and maybe it's my coding that is causing this issue. I have several characters in my app but this glitch even happens with 1 image.

`float moveUP`    == the only thing above the @interface viewcontroller.h file that's required

**ViewController.m**

```
@synthesize Next;     //= a button

@synthesize time;    //=NSTimer

@synthesize bird;     //=image

@synthesize platform;   //=image

-(void)movePlatform{

 moveUP=moveUP-0.1;  

    bird.center=CGPointMake(bird.center.x, bird.center.y -moveUP);  

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bird.frame, platform.frame)) {  
        [self bounce];
     }
}


-(void)bounce{

moveUP=+4.00;   
}


 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
 time=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.035 target:self selector:@selector(movePlatform) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tree.png"]];

  [super viewDidLoad];
 }

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}

@end
```

I need help, i don't know what to do to make that glitch dissapear.

Comment: What happens if you call `[time invalidate]` in `viewWillDisappear:`? What do you mean when you say it "glitches"?

Comment: I need the bird to bounce up and down. Not stopping the timer.  Instead for 1 second when i go to VC2 he jumps up and down quickly without ever hitting the platform. After that bird bounces normally again. That weird glitch happens for literally 1 second but you can clearly see it.

Comment: Don't use `NSTimer` for animations. Check out `CADisplayLink`, UIDynamics, or regular UIView animations.

Comment: The following may sound like a stupid question but i never uploaded an app into the app store before. This game i'm working on would be my 1st app. Am i allowed to upload an app into the app store without using Auto Layout on Xcode 5.1.1 or will the app get rejected automatically? I ask this because i unticked auto layout and the glitch went away.